# How can connect an Yongnuo YN 600 EX RT flash as master with an Yongnuo YN 560 IV as receiver mode

Tags: canon, flash, off-camera-flash

I want to connect my Yongnuo YN 600 EX RT flash so it works as master flash with an Yongnuo YN 560 IV flash as receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Since the YN600EX-RT uses the Canon RT wireless radio protocol and the YN560 IV uses the older Yongnuo YN560/RF605/RF603 protocol, the YN600EX-RT can not communicate directly with the YN560 IV. They use the same wireless frequencies, but each uses a different "language" to communicate the same information.

The easiest solution would probably be to use a YNE3-RX receiver attached to the hot foot of the YN560 IV. That *might* allow you to set manual power remotely, but it might not. If the YNE3-RX doesn't fire the flash when directly attached to the YN560 IV hot foot, then you could either:

- Use a PC cord between the YNE3-RX and the YN560 IV to send a "fire" command. All adjustments to the flash settings would need to be made directly on the flash.
- Tape over the TTL contacts on the YNE3-RX and attach it to the hot foot of the YN560 IV. The receiver would only send a "fire" command to the flash via the main pin. All adjustments to the flash settings would need to be made directly on the flash.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with radio protocols. And the YN-560 models don't do Canon's "smart" optical. So the only way to use the YN-600EX-RT as a wireless master to a YN-560IV as a slave without adding any addition gear (cable, YN-E3-RX, Phottix Laso Rx, etc.), is using the S1/S2 "dumb" optical slave modes on the YN-560 IV, and firing the YN-600EX-RT on-camera **out** of wireless master mode.

This is why a lot of us prefer Godox gear to Yongnuo gear: Yongnuo uses three, separate, mostly-incompatible radio systems (60x/560, 622, and RT), while [Godox only uses one integrated system](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-flash-system-overview/).  What you cannot do with the YN-600EX-RT and YN-560IV is exactly what you *can* do with a Godox TT685 and TT600 (with remote power control and HSS).